# copy pasting file from ubuntu guest os to host windows 8.1 os vmware

Tags: 16.04, vmware-workstation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine in Vmware 14 workstation on a 64 bit windows 8 machine.I have installed vmware tools in Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS but still I am not able to copy a file from the guest OS (Ubuntu) to the desktop of host OS windows 8.1. This file is located in home directory of Ubuntu Virtual machine where I log in. So what could be the cause of failure and how do I check it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by installing open-vm-tools-desktop

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

I uninstalled other vmware-tools which I installed with workstation 14 bundled download and open-vm-tools also uninstalled

```
  sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools-desktop
```